# Is it possible to set the stack size to greater than 10000?

Tags: texshop, stack

Sorry I can't post a minimal example but the document is available at [this link](http://www.stbarnabaschapel.net/book0.pdf) and it will give an idea of it's complexity. I have been expecting to run into difficulties for some time as there are thousands of `\hyperlink`-`\hypertarget` and `\ref`-`\label` pairs.  I have gone through the standard procedure for TexShop by altering my `texmf.cmf` file and rebuilding (`sudo fmtutil-sys --all`). I can alter my stack size, but if the value is greater than 10000 (e.g., 25000) then it seems to be ignored, after rebuilding I still get  TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [`parameter stack size=10000`].

[edit  14:08 UT]
In the light of a few comments below a bit more detail. I have three very simple macros and  can switch on and off hyper-linking. The \fbs macro behaves fine with hyperlinking; it builds without an error. The \fb macro however does not and creates a stack overflow.

```
\newcommand{\fb}[1]{%
{\hyperlink{bit:#1}{\color{magenta}\tt{#1}\hspace{-0.115cm}}}
%{\color{magenta}\tt{#1}\hspace{-0.115cm}}
}
\newcommand{\fbs}[1]{%
%{\hyperlink{bit:#1}{\color{magenta}\tt\small{#1}\hspace{-0.115cm}}}
{\color{magenta}\tt\small{#1}\hspace{-0.115cm}}
}
\newcommand{\fbt}[1]{%
{\hypertarget{bit:#1}{\color{magenta}\tt{#1}\hspace{-0.115cm}}}
%{\color{magenta}\tt{#1}\hspace{-0.115cm}}
}
```

Well I've tracked the cause of the error. I was using a

```
{\color{magenta}{\small $\overline{\mbox{RI}}$}}
```

which was replaced with a

```
 \fb{$\overline{\mbox{RI}}$}}
```

It seems that using this as a hyperlink was the issue; probably some form of recursion problem as already suggested.

Comment: I can't see why hyperref or \label should affect parameter stack significantly, are you sure you haven't got a macro looping somewhere?

Comment: It is difficult to overflow parameter stack size, you probably have a recursive macro.

Comment: Did you alter `stack_size` or `param_size`?

Comment: I altered stack_size

Comment: @Ulrike Will look for a recursive macro; it is possible. The behaviour is a bit strange. I have two hyperlink macros and one hypertarget will edit question.

Comment: why `\hspace{-0.115cm}}} ` that is: a negative space specified in cm followed by a word space (usually specified in font-specific em?)

Comment: @David yes em would be better; thanks for the tip

Comment: @SeanDanaher well really I meant remove the negative space, and the following word space:-)

Comment: Yes - a bit of historic cut and paste. I had not understood the significance of terminating a line with a % inside a macro